# onReceive() method is never called

Tags: java, android

Recently I have been interested in Android Development and a friend gave me the book "Android Application Development for Dummies". In the book, there is a example app entitled Silent Toggle Mode. Later on there it teaches you to make a home screen widget for the app. I have typed in everything from the book exactly but it still gives me an error notifying me that the onReceive() method is never called. Here is the code:

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;

public class AppWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

@Override
public void onRecieve(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if(intent.getAction()==null) {
        context.startService(new Intent(context, ToggleService.class));
    } else {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
    }
}
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    context.startService(new Intent(context, ToggleService.class));
}

public static class ToggleService extends IntentService {

    public ToggleService() {
        super("AppWidget$ToggleService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        ComponentName me=new ComponentName(this, AppWidget.class);
        AppWidgetManager mgr=AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);
        mgr.updateAppWidget(me, buildUpdate(this));
    }
    private RemoteViews buildUpdate(Context context) {
        RemoteViews updateViews=new  RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.widget);
        AudioManager audioManager=(AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Activity.AUDIO_SERVICE);

        if(audioManager.getRingerMode()==AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT) {
            updateViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.phoneState,R.drawable.phone_state_normal);

            audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
        } else {
            updateViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.phoneState,R.drawable.phone_state_silent);

            audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
        }
        Intent i=new Intent(this, AppWidget.class);

        PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);

        updateViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.phoneState, pi);

        return updateViews;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo, it's `onReceive()` and not `onRecieve()`. Write it like this:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
```

This is a good example of why we should always use the `@Override` annotation, it simplifies finding bugs such as this one.

Comment: Yup, using @Override would have found this at compile time.

Comment: *face slap* Thank you very much. Haha I spent about 2 hours trying to figure it out